what's the difference between write() and writev() system calls in Linux and their performance implications
I am currently working on a HPC(High Performance Computing) related project where I need to write data to a file in Linux. I have come across two system calls: write() and writev(). I am trying to understand the differences between these two calls and when it is appropriate to use each one. Additionally, I am interested in knowing if there are any performance implications when choosing one over the other.
I have read the man pages for both write() and writev(), but I am still unclear about the practical differences and performance considerations. I would like to know if there are any specific use cases where writev() is preferred over write() or vice versa.
Could someone please provide a clear explanation of the differences and any performance considerations when using these system calls? If possible, please include examples and any benchmarks that demonstrate the performance differences.
Thank you in advance!:-)

Write a simple C program that times 10,000 write calls and 10,000 writev calls. Minimize external influences. If you measure, then you will know.
